# How to import files into nebeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to copy some Java source files created on the local filesystem (macbook) into Netbeans. For some reason it doesn't allow this with copy paste. What's the best way to do this? I'd like the files to be copied into the project directory under the Netbeans folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a proper NetBeans java project (java app, java web app..etc..)
- Create a sample source file and see where it is being created and place your java file at that place also note the package structure.

Comment: This is the way to go. If you're familiar with an eclipse workspace, this will get in your way of understanding netbeans. A netbeans project has a root directory on your filesystem, and the source code is usually just kept under the src directory according the package structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an empty file where ever you need to copy the file on Netbeans. Give the empty file the same name as the one you need to copy. Open the file to be copied with a text editor and copy and paste the content on Netbeans and save it.